# Test about creating objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a homework and I'm required to create a class so the code behaves as expected.

```
// This is the test input
movie = new Movie("Star Wars"); 

// Expected Output     
[Movie "Star Wars"]  // Expected output
```

**My question is how do I get to it?**

As I understand it they are asking me to write a class in ES5. Here is my code so far

```
var Movie = function Movie(title) {
  this.title = title;
  this.header =  this.title = (title) ? "[Movie \"" + title + "\"]": "[Movie]";
  this.show = function(){
     console.log('Your movie is on theaters');
   }

}


movie = new Movie("Lord Of The Rings"); //  [object Object]
```

Am I missing something here?

UPDATE 1: Here is the code that solves it, as @loïc-faure-lacroix suggested.

```
var Movie = function Movie(title) {
this.title = title;
this.header =  this.title = (title) ? "[Movie \"" + title + "\"]": " [Movie]";
this.show = function(){
   console.log('Your movie is on theaters');
 }

}


 movie = new Movie("Lord Of The Rings"); //  [Movie "Lord of The Rings"] 
 movie = new Movie(); //  [Movie]
```

Comment: I'm assuming in your "Expected output", you don't want to change the name of the movie?

Comment: Everything is fine. Javascript doesn't automatically do these stuff nor other language can guess that you're expecting to show the title field.

Comment: `function Movie(title)` - Remove `Movie`. You're already giving the function a name on the other side of the equals sign.

Comment: This is supposed to be returned from the console.

Comment: The console output is not standardized though. Different environments will produce different results. For example in Chrome the output is `Movie {title: "[Movie "Lord Of The Rings"]", header: "[Movie "Lord Of The Rings"]"}`. So, trying to get the console to output something in a certain format is a futile task.

Comment: @J.Titus There’s no reason to remove it. It’s a matter of taste whether you want to name your functions or not.

Comment: @Xufox there's no point naming a function and then ghosting it with the same name.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix It may help at debugging if the function name isn’t automatically inferred from the variable name.

Comment: Your "updated" code seems to be exactly the same as your original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a way to convert an object to a string. Unless you're adding the object to a html element, then what you're looking for is to define a `toString` method.

```
Movie.prototype.toString = function () {
  return this.title
}
```

It will show the object in the console in some interpereter, but it's not clear if its supported by all consoles.

Technically, it won't work as some consoles  like firefox will use a fancy link to an object. But if you want to concatenate it to a string, then it will call toString and convert the object to string approriately. But the output of a raw object without transformation to string is, as far as I know, undefined.

Note:

It's useless to do the following because you already defined the function named Movie:

```
var Movie = function Movie() { ...}
```

Comment: This worked fine. I added your code inside the class declaration and it worked like a charm. Thanks so much. I'll update the question to show the implementation of your answer. 

Could you provide more information about why does it behave like that or why is the toString method relevant in this case?

Comment: @JaimeRios it's in the answer already. It convert the object to a string.

Comment: Oh, I see it now.